# An ODE with Gaussians

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, stability-in-odes, functional-calculus

I'm tackling an equation of this type: 
$$\left( a - b e^{-x^2} - e^{-x^2/2} \frac{1}{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} e^{- x^2 /2} \right) f(x) = g(x) $$ 
where $f(x)$ is my unknown and $g(x)$ is given, both are defined for $x\geq 0$, both smooth and square integrable, while $a$ and $b$ are positive parameters. Alas, the differential operator on the LHS isn't easy to invert. My attempts to compute the resolvent have consisted mostly of projecting $f(x)$ on various bases. How would *you* proceed?